# Ionic - How to access backgroundGeoLocation plugin in a controller

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to access backgroundGeoLocation plugin (https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation) in a controller, not in the app.js file.

Using the plugin this way, it works.

```
 .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
          $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
            // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
            // for form inputs)
            if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
              cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
              cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
            }
            if (window.StatusBar) {
              // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
              StatusBar.styleDefault();
            }
          });

          document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
            backgroundGeoLocation.configure(callbackFn, failureFn, {
              desiredAccuracy: 10,
              stationaryRadius: 20,
              distanceFilter: 30,
              locationService: 'ANDROID_DISTANCE_FILTER',
              debug: false,
              stopOnTerminate: false
            });
          });
})
```

However, outside the .run in app.js, the plugin is not defined, like in my controller :

```
angular.module('starter.login', [])

 // Controller de connexion
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $ionicPopup, $state, LoginService) {
  $scope.data = {};
  backgroundGeoLocation.configure(callbackFn, failureFn, {
      desiredAccuracy: 10,
      stationaryRadius: 20,
      distanceFilter: 30,
      locationService: 'ANDROID_DISTANCE_FILTER',
      debug: false,
      stopOnTerminate: false
    });
});
```

Is there a way to use the plugin in my controller ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code in your controller is that it will execute when the controller is initialised - i.e at runtime - but Cordova plugins are loaded dynamically so are not available until the `deviceready` event has fired. That's why your first code block works, because the call is placed inside a `deviceready` callback (you could actually just place it inside the existing `$ionicPlatform.ready` callback - it fires on the same event). You need to do a similar thing in your controller, i.e. wait for `deviceready` before attempting to call the plugin:

```
angular.module('starter.login', [])

 // Controller de connexion
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $ionicPopup, $state, LoginService, $ionicPlatform) {
  $scope.data = {};

  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    backgroundGeoLocation.configure(callbackFn, failureFn, {
      desiredAccuracy: 10,
      stationaryRadius: 20,
      distanceFilter: 30,
      locationService: 'ANDROID_DISTANCE_FILTER',
      debug: false,
      stopOnTerminate: false
    });
  });
});
```